# Как восстановить удаленную таблицу в Laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel

Допустим произошла такая ситуация, что в начале проекта Laravel я выполнил команду:

```
php artisan migrate
```

После чего создались 3 стандартные таблицы (в том числе таблица `users`).

Потом я удалил таблицу `users`, как мне обратно её создать с помощью миграций?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в оставшихся таблицах нет ничего важного, то можно выполнить:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Эта команда удалит все таблицы и повторит все миграции.

Если нужно откатить и заново повторить только последнюю миграцию, то можно выполнить:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Эта команда откатит последнюю миграцию и ее можно будет запустить снова.

Будьте внимательны, обе этих команды **удалят ранее созданные в миграции таблицы**.

---

Если вы удалили сам файл миграции, то его можно либо скопировать с [github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php), либо выполнить команду:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

Comment: а если удалил миграцию?

Comment: Удалили файл миграции? В таком случае никак, в ней описана структура таблицы, которую вы хотите создать заново.

Comment: и повторить php migrate никак нельзя? (это была таблица созданная при команде php migrate автоматически, таблица users)

Comment: @Romka, а как же `php artisan make:migration create_users_table` или просто скопировать с [github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php) ?

Comment: @РустамГимранов Если речь именно по нее, то да можно просто скопировать)

Comment: @LowCode можно, если есть сам файл миграции. Что мешает повторно запустить команду?

Comment: Всё, спасибо большое. "@Romka, а как же php artisan make:migration create_users_table или просто скопировать с github ?" - помогло.